# R sparse matrix power

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I'm using the Matrix package to create a large (~14000x14000) sparse matrix with a lot of zeros. Does anyone know the best way to calculate the power of this matrix?

I tried A_pow2 = A%^%2 but I get the error: Error in A %^% 2 : not a matrix. Here's a simple example that returns the same error:

```
A = matrix(3,2,2)
A = Matrix(A,sparse=TRUE)
Apow2 = A%^%2
```

Comment: is the `%^%` operator from the `Matrix` pkg? have you tried simply using `^` in place of `%^%`?

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer That would be a different operation, element-wise power.

Comment: @Roland thanks for clarification. i was unfamiliar with the `%^%` operator. just located it in the `expm` pkg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(edited thanks to @Roland's comments)

A custom function might be able to solve your issue.  Per documentation of `` ?expm::`%^%` ``

> Compute the k-th power of a matrix. Whereas x^k computes element wise
>   powers, x %^% k corresponds to k - 1 matrix multiplications, x %*% x
>   %*% ... %*% x.

We can write a new infix operator to perform the multiplication k-1 times.  Not sure how well it will scale, but it works in smaller examples.

```
> library(Matrix)
> library(expm)
> A = matrix(3,2,2)
> B = Matrix(A,sparse=TRUE)
> 
> # changed lapply to rep list
> `%^^%` = function(x, k) Reduce(`%*%`, rep(list(x), k))
> # per Roland for loop approach will be better on memory
> `%^^%` = function(x, k) {for (i in 1:(k - 1)) x <- x %*% x; x}
> 
> as.matrix(B%^^%2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18   18
[2,]   18   18
> A%^%2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   18   18
[2,]   18   18
```

Comment: `\`%^^%\` = function(x, k) Reduce(\`%*%\`, rep(list(x), k))`

Comment: but for memory reasons it might be preferable to use `for (i in 1:(k - 1)) x <- x %*% x` (which would possibly be optimized by JIT compilation).

Comment: thanks, I ended up doing something similar but just with a forloop using %*% as you did but it takes a really long time when scaled up to the 14000x14000 matrix I need to work with. Too bad. Ultimately, I'm looking for an efficient way of calculating the inverse. Ax = y --> I used solve(A,y) but it takes about a minute with the matrix under question. Anyways good answer thanks Roland and Adam!